# maven Failed to read artifact descriptor for raml

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am trying to follow steps from this article and include a build step for my project

https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/maven-plugin.md

problem is it keeps complaining about not being able to read the artifact, the error line is

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.raml:jaxrs-to-raml:pom:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
```

I can confirm that my local maven repo looks like

~/.m2/repository/org/raml/plugins/jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin/1.3.4-SNAPSHOT/

jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin-1.3.4-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin-1.3.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin-1.3.4-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
maven-metadata-local.xml
jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin-1.3.4-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that maven cannot find the artifact:

```
org.raml:jaxrs-to-raml:pom:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT
```

That is a dependency of:

```
org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.4-SNAPSHOT
```

Make sure your repository contains the first artifact either by compiling it yourself or by adding the right remote repository

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem. It's said in the document:

- Clone this repository or download a snapshot.
- On the cloned repository, go to the
  jaxrs-to-raml/com.mulesoft.jaxrs.raml.generator folder, and execute
  mvn install
- Once installed, go to the jaxrs-to-raml/jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin
  folder and run mvn install.

But it couldn't work with the above problem.

Actually I installed **everything** in this repo, and that solved my problem.